# Instagram get user ID from username

Tags: api, instagram-api, userid

I recently found out from my employer that a public access token is no longer needed for obtaining a user ID from a user name which is great but I cannot find the relative documentation. I have been on the Instagram api and I cannot find this information or how it is achieved.

I found the solution using a client_ID like so.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&client_id=[CLIENT ID]
```

Comment: Please note that urgency does not belong in questions - your readership are volunteers, and they will answer at their leisure. Furthermore, why would you add it back in again after you have solved it? Is it to be regarded as urgent in perpetuity?

Comment: Thanks, vote removed. As far as I know your rep is not damaged if you receive downvotes that are later rescinded. In any case you should not worry about one or two downvotes - it is only if you get a large number of them that your account can be temporarily locked against new questions - and even then you can reverse the auto-ban by answering a few questions.

Comment: With regard to work, it may be worth discussing any difficulties with your manager. Any company who is worth working for will make a good effort to reduce your sources of anxiety - stressed programmers are rarely productive, especially over the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using a client_ID like so.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&client_id=[CLIENT ID]
```

Comment: This does not work anymore as of June 1, 2016 - with the new Instagram API change

Answer (score 2):

With code you can use `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1`
e.g. https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1

Without Code you can use the site:
https://www.thekeygram.com/find-instagram-user-id/